# Mocking StreamWriter (C# Moq)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mocking, tdd, moq

I am writing a method that will write to a text file. I am still trying to wrap my head around Dependency Inversion.

The issue I appear to be having is with mocking StreamWriter.

Here is my test, I commented out one of the setup lines, as this is where my issue is.

```
[Test]
    public void WriteToAutomationLog_FileDoesNotExist_CreateFile()
    {
        //arrange
        mockDirectoryWrapper.Setup(_ => _.Exists(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
        mockFileWrapper.Setup(_ => _.Exists(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
        mockFileWrapper.Setup(_ => _.CreateText(logFile.GetAutomationLogsPath() + fileName)).Verifiable();
        //mockFileWrapper.Setup(_ => _.CreateText(logFile.GetAutomationLogsPath() + fileName)).Returns(new StreamWriter(fileName)).Verifiable();

        //act
        logFile.WriteToAutomationLog(fileName, message);

        //assert
        mockFileWrapper.Verify(_ => _.CreateText(logFile.GetAutomationLogsPath() + fileName), Times.Exactly(1));
    }
```

Here is my method I am testing on

```
public void WriteToAutomationLog(string fileName, string message)
    {
        //Ensure the automation logs path still exists.
        if (_directoryWrapper.Exists(automationLogsPath))
        {
            //Check if file exists
            if (_fileWrapper.Exists(automationLogsPath + fileName))
            {
                //Append to log file
                using (StreamWriter sw = _fileWrapper.AppendText(automationLogsPath + fileName))
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Create new file
                using (StreamWriter sw = _fileWrapper.CreateText(automationLogsPath + fileName))
                {
                    sw.Write(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have wrappers for the Directory and File class. The issue I am having is when I call sw.Write(message), sw is null in my test. When I use the commented out line of code that returns a StreamWriter, I get an error saying access to the file is denied. However I do not want to actually read the file on the hard drive. How can I go about mocking StreamWriter?

On a side note, if I comment out sw.Write(message), my test passes. This issue came up when I added another test to test sw.Write, so when I added that code my old test broke (the one that I posted).

Comment: On a side note, toss mocking in the bin.   Unless you need to test against hardware that you don't have like a flight management computer; radar unit; or microwave, you should be testing against actual production code; databases and communication APIs.   All mocking does is to give you a false sense of confidence

Comment: `StreamWriter` is an implementation concern that can also be abstracted out as well.

Comment: @MickyD, But in true unit testing, aren't we supposed to mock out ALL of the dependencies? Ideally, we would have another integration test library to test the code with all production dependencies in place.

Comment: @ShervinShahrdar not at all.  You only mock out that which is _unavailable; inaccessible;_ or _expensive_ to test.   For example, our firm interfaces with or controls maritime equipment which gets mocked out because the only way to test it is to be on the boat

Comment: I disagree with @MickyD. I mock out the filesystem because it's a pain in the rear to deal with cleaning up persistent storage to ensure a deterministic environment for each execution/iteration of a new test. I already know the filesystem works. Why do I need to deal with platform-dependent filesystem intricacies and unnecessary cleanup work? Isolating a unit (by mocking) also helps root cause analysis because you don't have a giant suite of functionality to debug through to find the point of failure. Have your unit tests that have mocked deps and build integration testing on top of that.

Comment: Unit tests assist the developer with refactoring. Integration testing ensures a quality product. Both are necessary and not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @void.pointer  _” I mock out the filesystem because it's a pain”_ - let’s hope your System works in PROD. https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/have-you-unit-tested-that-aileron-servo/amp/

Comment: Why wouldn't it work in prod? Filesystem is filesystem. If it doesn't work, there are bigger issues. And you didn't address the other concerns. I think it's ironic that your blog talks about how religious mocking is, but you seem to religiously advocate against it with irrationality.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up refactoring my code to use the File.WriteAllText and File.AppendText so I didn’t need to add another dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create mock for StreamWriter and return it in your currently commented out line instead the actual StreamWriter.

Then it won't access the file. You can just check that `Write(string)` method with given message was actually called on the StreamWriter mock.